# Some little Question from Set-theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\Sigma$ be a ﬁnite alphabet. Prove that $|\{L \subseteq\Sigma^∗ : L \text{ is finite}\} | = \aleph_0$

How I can prove it  formally, I understand this intuitively, but do not really know how to translate this formal mathematical language.

And a hint how I prove it formally , too :
***For every language $L$ it holds that $L\subseteq L^*$***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $\Sigma^*$ is countably infinite. Next show that for a countably infinite set $A$, the set $\{B\subseteq A\mid B\text{ is finite}\}$ is countably infinite.

It suffices to show this for $A=\Bbb N$, and the function: $$B\mapsto\sum_{i\in B}2^i$$
gives you such a bijection in that case.